# Regex neglect Pattern in C#

Tags: c#, regex

[image]

I will delete all matches result(blue area) form file name to remove the extra strings so I Want to delete "Part " and the "   " and leave the numbers in the red area, How can i achieve that pattern?

Comment: Do you want to remove `-` as well?

Comment: Use `-Part-\d+|^Part\s+|(?<=^Part\s+\d+)\s+` regex pattern. But still you have to replace `-` with spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
-Part-\d+|^Part\s+|(?<=^Part\s+\d+)\s+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Sample code:

```
string[] input = {
    "102Redirect-http-to-https-in-iis-Part-102.mp4",
    "4Events-in-the-life-cycle-of-a-web-application-Part-4.mp4",
    "Part 5   Menu control in asp net.mp4",
    "Part 153   Menu control in asp net.mp4"
};
string[] output = input.Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, @"-Part-\d+|^Part\s+|(?<=^Part\s+\d+)\s+", string.Empty))
                       .ToArray();
foreach (string s in output)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
102Redirect-http-to-https-in-iis.mp4
4Events-in-the-life-cycle-of-a-web-application.mp4
5Menu control in asp net.mp4
153Menu control in asp net.mp4
```

Comment: +1 for nice work with diagram and sample code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using regex, simply replace :

```
String fileName=fileName.replace("-","");
fileName=fileName.replace("Part","");
fileName=fileName.replace(new Regex("   ",""); // or you can use \t of regex which take tabulations.
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove "Part", along with the whitespace and numbers, and restrict it to only occurring at the beginning of a line.

^Part\s\d+\s{3}